# Stackoverflow Exception in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am getting stackoverflow Exception in ASP.net C# code. the app goes into break mode. The records that i am fetching are above 1000, it breaks if i pass the range 1,35. it works fine if the range is up to 30. the code is simply generating html, we are using the generated html as report. can some one please help?

below is my code;

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace ARF.UI.Pages
{
    public partial class fromtoinvoiceofficecopy : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string from = Request.QueryString["FromInvoiceNo"];
            string to = Request.QueryString["ToInvoiceNo"];

            Double FromInvoiceNum = Convert.ToDouble(from);
            Double ToInvoiceNum = Convert.ToDouble(to);

            DataSet ds = DAL.ReportData.Rpt_NonSaleTaxInvoiceByInvoiceNum(FromInvoiceNum, ToInvoiceNum);
            DataTable NonSaleTaxInvoiceHeader = ds.Tables[0];
            DataRow row = NonSaleTaxInvoiceHeader.Rows[0];
            string note = row["Notes"].ToString();
            DataTable NonSaleTaxInvoiceDetail = ds.Tables[1];

            //myDiv.InnerHtml = "From: "+from+"<br>"+"To: "+to;
            myDiv.InnerHtml = CreateHTMLTableFromDatatable(NonSaleTaxInvoiceHeader, NonSaleTaxInvoiceDetail);
        }
        public static string CreateHTMLTableFromDatatable(DataTable dtItems, DataTable dtDetails)
        {
            string html = "";
            StringBuilder htmlStr = new StringBuilder("");
            double TotalGrossAmt = 0;
            double TotalDiscount = 0;
            double TotalNetAmt = 0;
            double Freight = 0;
            //add rows
            for (int i = 0; i < dtItems.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                htmlStr.Append("<div align='center' class='hdrcontent'><div class='logotxt'><img src='../Images/d_logo.png' style='width:60px'><b>XYZ Laboratories</b></div><div class='addr'>XYZ Road, XYZ CITY, XYZ<br>Tel:   Fax # </div></div><br><br>");
                htmlStr.Append("<b>");
                htmlStr.Append("<table class='hdrtbl'>");
                htmlStr.Append("<tr>");
                htmlStr.Append("<td>" + "Customer Code:" + "</td>");
                htmlStr.Append("<td>" + dtItems.Rows[i]["Code"].ToString() + "</td>");
                htmlStr.Append("<td></td>");
                htmlStr.Append("<td>" + "Invoice#:" + "</td>");
                htmlStr.Append("<td>"+dtItems.Rows[i]["InvoiceNumber"].ToString()+"</td>");
                htmlStr.Append("</tr>");
                htmlStr.Append("<tr>");
                htmlStr.Append("<td>Customer Name:</td>");
                htmlStr.Append("<td>"+dtItems.Rows[i]["InvoiceTo"]+"</td>");
                htmlStr.Append("<td></td>");
                htmlStr.Append("<td>Date:</td>");
                htmlStr.Append("<td>" + string.Format("{0:yyyyMMdd}", dtItems.Rows[i]["Date"])+ "</td>");
                htmlStr.Append("</tr>");
                htmlStr.Append("<tr>");
                htmlStr.Append("<td>Address:</td>");
                htmlStr.Append("<td>" + dtItems.Rows[i]["Address"] + "</td>");
                htmlStr.Append("<td></td>");
                htmlStr.Append("<td>DC Number:</td>");
                htmlStr.Append("<td>" + dtItems.Rows[i]["DeliveryChallanNo"] + "</td>");
                htmlStr.Append("</tr>");
                htmlStr.Append("<tr>");
                htmlStr.Append("<td>Mobile No:</td>");
                htmlStr.Append("<td>" + dtItems.Rows[i]["Mobile"] + "</td>");
                htmlStr.Append("<td></td>");
                htmlStr.Append("<td>BILTY Number:</td>");
                htmlStr.Append("<td>" + dtItems.Rows[i]["TRRRNo"] + "</td>");
                htmlStr.Append("</tr>");
                htmlStr.Append("<tr>");
                htmlStr.Append("<td>Forwarded Through:</td>");
                htmlStr.Append("<td>" + dtItems.Rows[i]["CarrierMS"] + "</td>");
                htmlStr.Append("<td></td>");
                htmlStr.Append("<td>Total Cartons:</td>");
                htmlStr.Append("<td>" + dtItems.Rows[i]["Cartons"] + "</td>");
                htmlStr.Append("</tr>");
                htmlStr.Append("</table>");
                htmlStr.Append("</b><br><br>");

                DataRow[] childs = lookupInvoiceDetails(dtDetails, dtItems.Rows[i][0].ToString());
                int length = childs.Length;
                htmlStr.Append("<tr>");
                htmlStr.Append("<table class='tbl'>");
                htmlStr.Append("<tr class='hdrsub'>");
                htmlStr.Append("<td>Product Name</td><td>Pack Size</td><td>Qty</td><td>Bonus</td>");
                htmlStr.Append("<td>Batch<br>Number</td><td>Rate (Rs)</td><td>GROSS AMT <br>(Rs) </td><td>Discount <br>%age </td><td>Discount<br>Amount<br>(Rs) </ td><td>Net Amount<br>(Rs) </td>");
                htmlStr.Append("</tr>");
                foreach(DataRow dr in childs)
                {
                    htmlStr.Append("<tr>");
                    htmlStr.Append("<td>"+dr["ItemAndUnitPacking"]+"</td>");
                    htmlStr.Append("<td>"+dr["PackSizeDisplay"] +"</td>");
                    htmlStr.Append("<td>"+dr["QTY"]+"</td>");
                    htmlStr.Append("<td>"+dr["Bonus"]+"</td>");
                    htmlStr.Append("<td>"+dr["BatchNumber"]+"</td>");
                    htmlStr.Append("<td>"+dr["UnitPrice"]+"</td>");
                    htmlStr.Append("<td>"+dr["GrossAmtRs"]+"</td>");
                    htmlStr.Append("<td>"+dr["DiscountPercentage"] +"</td>");
                    htmlStr.Append("<td>"+dr["TradeDiscount"] +"</td>");
                    htmlStr.Append("<td>"+ dr["NetAmountRs"] + "</td>");

                    TotalGrossAmt += Convert.ToDouble(dr["GrossAmtRs"].ToString());
                    TotalDiscount += Convert.ToDouble(dr["TradeDiscount"].ToString());
                    TotalNetAmt += Convert.ToDouble(dr["NetAmountRs"].ToString());
                    Freight = Convert.ToDouble(dr["Freight"].ToString());

                    htmlStr.Append("</tr>");
                }
                htmlStr.Append("<tr>");
                htmlStr.Append("<td colspan='5'>Invoice Remarks (If Any) :</td>");
                htmlStr.Append("<td><b>Total</b></td>");
                htmlStr.Append("<td><b>"+TotalGrossAmt.ToString("#,##0.00") + "</b></td>");
                htmlStr.Append("<td></td>");
                htmlStr.Append("<td><b>"+TotalDiscount.ToString("#,##0.00") + "</b></td>");
                htmlStr.Append("<td><b>"+TotalNetAmt.ToString("#,##0.00") + "</b></td>");
                htmlStr.Append("</tr>");
                htmlStr.Append("<tr>");
                htmlStr.Append("<td colspan='5'></td>");
                htmlStr.Append("<td colspan='4'><b>LESS BILTY Charges</b></td>");
                htmlStr.Append("<td><b>"+Freight.ToString("#,##0.00") + "</b></td>");
                htmlStr.Append("</tr>");
                htmlStr.Append("<tr>");
                htmlStr.Append("<td colspan='5'></td>");
                htmlStr.Append("<td colspan='4'><b>NET PAYABLE</b></td>");
                htmlStr.Append("<td><b>"+(TotalNetAmt-Freight).ToString("#,##0.00") + "</b></td>");
                htmlStr.Append("</tr>");
                htmlStr.Append("<tr>");
                htmlStr.Append("<td colspan='10'><b>WARRANTY:-</b> I,under Section:23(1)(i) of the Drug Act, 1976,hereby give this warranty that the Drugs described in");
                htmlStr.Append("this invoice and sold by us do not cotravene in any way with the provisions of section 23 of the");
                htmlStr.Append("Drugs Act,1976.</td>");
                htmlStr.Append("</tr>");
                htmlStr.Append("<tr><td colspan='10'>&nbsp;</td></tr>");
                htmlStr.Append("<tr>");
                htmlStr.Append("<td colspan='10'><b>TERMS & CONDITIONS:-</b><br>");
                htmlStr.Append("1.Damage / Breakage / Leakage of stock will only be entertained, if informed in writing within 15 days from date of invoice.<br>");
                htmlStr.Append("2.Claims of Near Expiry Stock will be entertained, if informed in wrting before three(3) months prior to expired.<br>");
                htmlStr.Append("3.Your complaints will only be entertained, if it will be submitted in writing to Head office at ");
                htmlStr.Append("</td>");
                htmlStr.Append("</tr>");
                htmlStr.Append("</table>");
                htmlStr.Append("<br>");
                htmlStr.Append("</tr>");
                htmlStr.Append("<table class='footertbl'>");
                htmlStr.Append("<tr>&nbsp;</tr>");
                htmlStr.Append("<tr>");
                htmlStr.Append("<td style='width:150px;'><b>CHECKED BY:</b></td><td> --------------------------- </td><td></td><td></td><td></td>");
                htmlStr.Append("<td><b>ISSUED BY:</b></td><td colspan='2'>-------------------------</td>");
                htmlStr.Append("</tr>");
                htmlStr.Append("<tr>");
                htmlStr.Append("<td><br><br><b>Printed date "+ DateTime.Now + "</b></td>");
                htmlStr.Append("<tr>");
                htmlStr.Append("</table>");
            }
            htmlStr.Append("</table>");
            return htmlStr.ToString();
        }
        static public DataRow[] lookupInvoiceDetails(DataTable dtDetails, string qry)
        {
            DataRow[] foundInvoiceDetails = dtDetails.Select("NonSaleTaxInvoiceId = '" + qry + "'");

            if (foundInvoiceDetails.Length != 0)
            {
                //return foundInvoiceDetails;

            }
            return foundInvoiceDetails;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Whats the minimum amount of code you need to reproduce it

Comment: @TheGeneral calling htmlStr.Append(); a few thousand times

Comment: Its highly unlikely `StringBuilder` is causing the stackoverflow exception

Comment: I can't see anything genuinely recursive here - ugly, sure - but not recursive; it doesn't *look* like anything here should do a stack-dive, either; are you sure the stack-overflow isn't coming from something you're not showing us? stack-overflow almost always means either recursion, or making inappropriate use of `stackalloc`, and this code has neither

Comment: @FayyazAli no, you can call `Append` on a `StringBuilder` quite safely; it won't be doing a stack-dive

Comment: @TheGeneral, what you suspect? An unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' occurred in System.Runtime.Serialization.dll

Comment: @FayyazAli none of this code is touching serialization; if that is what the error message says, you're *looking in the wrong place* - this isn't the cause; things that *might* touch serialization even if you're not using it explicitly: session / session-state / view-state / cache

Comment: Its not apparent, this is why i asked, how much can you pull out and reproduce the problem

Comment: @TheGeneral to me the code looks recursive as if the records are lets say 500, it is calling the methods a few thousand times.

Comment: @FayyazAli that doesn't mean recursive; I can see no recursive paths here

Comment: As @MarcGravell put it, its not recursive from what is shown

Comment: @TheGeneral this is the max that i could pull out

Comment: `for (int i = 0; i < dtItems.Rows.Count; i++)` how much is your count? + I think it might help to show us what this piece is doing: `DAL.ReportData.Rpt_NonSaleTaxInvoiceByInvoiceNum(FromInvoiceNum, ToInvoiceNum)`

Comment: Not your issue, but `Convert.ToDouble(dr["GrossAmtRs"].ToString())` would (depending on the real type of the data) also work without the `.ToString()`

Comment: OT `Freight = Convert.ToDouble(...` - should there be a `+=` there?

Comment: Can you comment out the call to `CreateHTMLTableFromDatatable`, to check whether the problem is there or in your DAL method?

Comment: @AsheraH the count is in 1000s, the DAL.ReportData is call to procedure that is returning 2 datatables.

Comment: @HansKeﬆing if i comment out CreateHTMLTableFromDatatable, no stackoverflow exception. it means the problem is in generating html

Comment: can someone recommend a better way or should i process the request in chunks

Comment: As alternate solution, make use of controls that are *designed* to format data into html, such as [DataList](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.datalist).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the problem by specifying the capacity and Max capacity of StringBuilder, below is the line that i changed;

```
StringBuilder htmlStr = new StringBuilder(276438, Int32.MaxValue);
```

Again this is a temporary solution. i am open to better suggestion.